# How to upload video using multipart/form-data and axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, request, multipartform-data

I am trying to implement video upload using multipart/form-data and axios.

But when trying to upload a split video file into chunks in bytes. The program gives this error:

```
AxiosError.call(axiosError, error.message, code, config, request, response);
             ^
AxiosError: read ECONNRESET
    at AxiosError.from (d:\PH Auto\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios.cjs:725:14)
    at RedirectableRequest.handleRequestError (d:\PH Auto\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios.cjs:2467:25)
    at RedirectableRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at eventHandlers.<computed> (d:\PH Auto\node_modules\follow-redirects\index.js:14:24)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:494:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  syscall: 'read',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  errno: -4077
```

My code that converts video to chunks of bytes and tries to send them.

```
async function getChunk(videoPath, fileSize, params, cookie2, token, file_id, file_time, file_key, useragent){
    let chunks = [];

    let readStream = fs.createReadStream(videoPath);

      let stat = fs.statSync(videoPath);
      let step = 1;

      let chunk;

      readStream.on('readable', function() {
        while (null !== (chunk = readStream.read(chunkSize))) {
          chunks.push(chunk);
        };
      });
      
      readStream.on('end', async () => {
        for (i in chunks) {
          console.log(`Yes, prepared cell`)
          await uploadVideo(chunks[i], Number(i)+1, fileSize, chunks.length, params, cookie2, token, file_id, file_time, file_key, useragent);
          step++;
        };

        // await fs.unlinkSync(videoPath);

        return
      })
};

async function uploadVideo(chunks, step, fileSize, chunksLength, params, cookie2, token, file_id, file_time, file_key, useragent) {
    
    function bufferToStream(binary) {

        const readableInstanceStream = new Readable({
          read() {
            this.push(binary);
            this.push(null);
          }
        });
  
        return readableInstanceStream;
      };

    let firstChunkSize;
    let secondChunkSize;

    if (step == 1) {
        firstChunkSize = 0;
        secondChunkSize = chunkSize;
    } else if (step == chunksLength) {
        firstChunkSize = chunkSize * (step - 1) + step - 1;
        secondChunkSize = fileSize - 1;
    } else {
        firstChunkSize = chunkSize * (step - 1) + step - 1;
        secondChunkSize = chunkSize * (step - 1) + step - 1 + chunkSize;
    }

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('value', bufferToStream(chunks));

    let result = await axios.post(params, formData, {
       data: {
        token: token,
        file_id: file_id,
        file_time: file_time,
        file_key: file_key
       },
       headers: {
        'cookie': cookie2,
        'user-agent': useragent,
        'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'content-disposition': `attachment; filename=${encodeURI(`./video/${videoNames[0]}`)}`,
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data;',
        'content-range': `bytes ${firstChunkSize}-${secondChunkSize}/${fileSize}`,
        'origin': 'https://rt.pornhub.com',
        'referer': 'https://rt.pornhub.com/upload/videodata'
       }
    });

    return result
};
```

I also tried to make a similar request via request bible, but the error was exactly the same. Perhaps I'm somehow sending the multipart/form-data incorrectly. But I'm not sure.

The request that downloads the chunk:
[image]

Comment: @Dai I removed `data` because I have it in the link as parameters and left only the `formData`. The error didn't go away